# AOL is rejecting emails from my client's website, how can I troubleshoot?

Tags: email

I am a bit of an email noob.  My website is trying to send email from a contact form using the PHP mail function.  This works fine when sending it to my Gmail account, but AOL rejects it.  I have set up an RDNS record for the client ( fallsroadsunoco.com )

```
Macintosh:~ TAmoyal$ nslookup 67.23.28.65
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
65.28.23.67.in-addr.arpa    name = fallsroadsunoco.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

I have even set up an MX record (although I think this is irrelevant because that should only be needed for receiving email).  I did some poking around and randomly saw this on my server...but 2 things to note with this output:

1. i changed the receiving email address to blahblahblah@aol.com to keep it anonymous
2. bandop.com was my RDNS host name at the time this email was sent.  i changed it to the client's host name fallsroadsunoco.com to see if that would help...and it didn't

```
sudo more var/spool/postfix/deferred/0/0F902E4F7E
trace_flags=0SO^Lwww-data@comR^Lwww-data@comMN!Received: by bandop.com (Postfix)N5124671id 0F902E4F7E; Sat,ime=1246714223Alog_message_origin=localA
 4 Jul 2009 13:30:23 +0000 (UTC)N+Date: Sat,  4 Jul 2009 13:30:23 +0000 (UTC)N.From: MAILER-DAEMON@com (Mail Delivery System)N,Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to SenderNTo: www-data@
comNAuto-Submitted: auto-repliedNMIME-Version: 1.0N<Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;N,  boundary="B68D0E4F7D.1246714223/bandop.com"NContent-Transfer-Enco
ding: 8bitN2Message-Id: <20090704133023.0F902E4F7E@bandop.com>NN$This is a MIME-encapsulated message.NN"--B68D0E4F7D.1246714223/bandop.comN!Content-Description: NotificationN*Content-Ty
pe: text/plain; charset=us-asciiNN+This is the mail system at host bandop.com.NN;I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could notN<be delivered to one or more recipients. It'
s attached below.NN7For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.NN9If you do so, please include this problem report. You canN8delete your own text from the attached returned 
message.NN"                   The mail systemNNO<blahblahblah@aol.com>: host mailin-02.mx.aol.com[64.12.137.89] said: 501 SYNTAXND    ERROR IN PARAMETERS OR ARGUMENTS (in reply to MAIL F
ROM command)NN"--B68D0E4F7D.1246714223/bandop.comN$Content-Description: Delivery reportN%Content-Type: message/delivery-statusNNReporting-MTA: dns; bandop.comNX-Postfix-Queue-ID: B68D0E
Status: 5.0.0N%Remote-MTA: dns; mailin-02.mx.aol.comNBDiagnostic-Code: smtp; 501 SYNTAX ERRO(UTC)NN,Final-Recipient: rfc822; blahblahblah@aol.comNAction: failedN
 IN PARAMETERS OR ARGUMENTSNN"--B68D0E4F7D.1246714223/bandop.comN(Content-Description: Undelivered MessageNContent-Type: message/rfc822NContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitNN1Received: by ba
ndop.com (Postfix, from userid 33)N5    id B68D0E4F7D; Sat,  4 Jul 2009 13:30:22 +0000 (UTC)NTo: blahblahblah@aol.comN!Subject: Your contact form works!N$Date: Sat, 4 Jul 2009 09:30:22 -
X-Priority: 3N?X-Mailer: PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.4]NMIME-Version: 1.0NContent-Transfer-Enallsroadsunoco.com>N
oding: 8bitN)Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"NNName: Tony AmoyalN
encoding=8bitE03@gmail.comMessage:NCan you see this?NNN$--B68D0E4F7D.1246714223/bandop.com--XA
```

Any idea why only AOL would be rejecting my messages? Also note that they are not making it to the SPAM folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that you are not correctly setting the FROM header on the PHP side.  It would help to post the PHP code that was used to send the email.

Comment: I am pretty sure the code just uses the php mail function which should work.  I also imagine that if the problem is in the code, google would not accept the emails.  Do you still think I should investigate this?

Comment: The parameters that you pass the to the PHP mail function can be tricky, and different service providers can be picky about what kinds of mail and what format of headers they accept.

Answer (score 11):

A packet capture showing the SMTP conversation would be useful here, probably more so than the contents of your mail log.  Also be advised that AOL's mail servers are pretty psycho about who they receive mail from.   Check out their FAQ at http://postmaster.aol.com/guidelines/standards.html:

- AOL's servers will not accept
  connections from unsecured systems.
  These include open relays, open
  proxies, open routers, or any other
  system that has been determined to be
  available for unauthorized use.

  Ensure all forms on your web server
  are secure. If you use formmail
  scripts, ensure they cannot be used
  to send spam.

  **AOL's mail servers will not accept connections from systems that use
  dynamically assigned or residential
  IP addresses.**

  Organizations may not hard code AOL's
  MX records into their configuration
  files.

  **All e-mail must be compliant with RFCs 2821 and 2822.**

  **AOL's mail servers will reject connections from any IP address that
  does not have reverse DNS (a PTR
  record). All e-mail servers
  connecting to AOL's mail servers must
  have valid and meaningful (not
  dynamic-looking) reverse DNS records.
  For example:  Meaningful RDNS:
  mail.domain.com Generic RDNS:
  1.2.3.4.domain.isp.com**

  AOL may reject connections from
  servers whose recipient lists
  consistently generate a higher than
  10% bounce failure rate. (i.e. over
  10% of a sender's mailing list is
  destined for users that do not exist
  on our system)

  **AOL may reject connections from senders who are unable to accept at
  least 90% of the bounce-return
  messages (mailer-daemon failure/error
  messages) destined for their
  systems.**

  Complaints submitted by AOL members
  may be used as a basis for refusing
  connections from any mail server.

  Persons sending bulk mail from the
  whitelisted IP Address must
  immediately remove any e-mail address
  which causes a permanent failure
  "bounce" message to be generated with
  one of the following error codes: 
  550 "AOL username" Is Not Accepting
  Mail From This Sender  550 Mailbox
  not found 550 We would love to have
  gotten this email to
  example_user@aim.com. But, your
  recipient never logged onto their
  free AIM Mail account. Please contact
  them and let them know that they're
  missing out on all the super features
  offered by AIM Mail. And by the way,
  they're also missing out on your
  email.

  AOL, LLC does not authorize the use
  of its proprietary computers and
  computer network to accept, transmit
  or distribute unsolicited bulk
  e-mail. AOL's unsolicited bulk e-mail
  policy can be found at our website.

I've **bolded** the points you may want to look into.  I've had trouble with sending mail to them in the past, which turned out to be a misconfigured PTR record for the server that was sending the mail.  I think you're OK there, but you should check the others out.

Comment: This is an excellent response, RainyRat.  I will add that even after you have done all these things and even if you setup a "feedback" address so AOl can report spam to you, they sometimes seem to reject email for no good reason.  After checking all the above points, you may find you have to wait a few days before AOL starts accepting your email again.

Comment: +1 as I was just about to point this user to AOL's technical standards for email delivery:

http://postmaster.aol.com/guidelines/standards.html

Comment: Thanks for the great response, Rainy Rat.  I will look into these items today. My RDNS seems cool because it is a domain name, and I am using a static IP address.  Does the last bold item mean that I need to have an incoming mail server set up to receive bounced emails?

Comment: I think so, yes.  I guess it's to stop spam sent with fake "from" addresses.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing email, you want to sign up for a [feedback loop](http://postmaster.aol.com/fbl/index.html) with AOL, and then to be on the [AOL whitelist](http://postmaster.aol.com/whitelist/whitelist_guides.html) (which requires your server to be well behaved).  It's worth it in the long run.

Post a capture of the SMTP conversation (anonymized as you like) so we can help more.

Comment: Looks like the feedback loop and AOL whitelist are for people sending bulk mail.  This question is for emails sent via a contact form.  I don't think the whitelist should be necessary.

Comment: can you tell me how to capture an smtp conversation? i am using an ubuntu vps from slicehost

Comment: `tcpdump -s 0 -i eth0 -w foo.pcap tcp port 25` would be a good place to start.  That will make a file `foo.pcap` that you can read with wireshark or tcpdump later.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message the FROM syntax isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem but mostly it was with receiving e-mail notifications from forums in which I had placed a post. It wasn't until about two weeks ago when I opened up a new website that I found this problem to be much more serious.

My new website e-mail address was being rejected by AOL and would not show up in the spam folders. Of course my Yahoo and Gmail accounts would accept the e-mails. So I contacted AOL and received help from an upper-level technician.

After running some quick tests, he said that he knew the problem was that AOL was identifying my website and the forums as some kind of spam prone websites. He seriously suggested that I contact each and every one of these website's hosts and asked them to logon to postmaster.aol.com and then send AOL their IP connection address.

I told him that I doubted any of these large companies would do anything that he has suggested but I tried anyway. I contacted my websites host and relayed the information to him with instructions on how to go about sending AOL their IP connection address.

To no surprise, my website host replied with suggestions of what I can do because they had no intention of sending AOL anything. I had told the technician that his solution, (actually, AOL's solution), was unrealistic and that AOL should allow the paid user to adjust his or her own spam filters.

That is pretty much where it ends so now I have my new websites e-mail set up so that anyone who sends e-mail to that website will have it redirected to my Gmail account which will then redirected to AOL.

This is just making my life a little more complicated and I can see my future with AOL coming to a quick end shortly.